# Iterate datagrid and store data to datatable in silverilght?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am doin silverlight 4 app.

i want to iterate throught a datagrid and get the data and send it to buisness layer via wcf.

In **asp.net, datatable** was used to store data.

In **silverligth** how can this be achieved. what is used instead of datatable for this purpose?

Any idea.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DataTable` object in Silverlight as the source of a `DataGrid` (although it's more common to wrap the `DataTable` in a `CollectionView` to allow for implicit grouping/filtering etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class with fields similar to DataTable, and use a List to send the data to wcf in only one step.